# (React and Redux) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am working with React and Redux and I am getting the error mentioned in the title. This is how it looks in the browser, when I try to access the frontend -

[image]

Here is the code -

ProductActions.js -

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL
 } from '../constants/productConstants'

 export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try{
       dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })
       
       const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products/')

       dispatch({
           type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
           payload:data
       })
     }catch(error){
       dispatch({
           type:PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
           payload:error.response && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message
                : error.message,
       })
     }
  }
```

HomeScreen.js -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';

function HomeScreen() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
    const {error, loading, products} = productList

  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(listProducts())

  },[dispatch] )

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
      {loading ? <h2>Loading...</h2>
          :error ? <h3>{error}</h3>
              :
              <Row>
                  {products.map((product) => (
                    <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                      <Product product={product} />
                    </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    }
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

ProductReducers.js -

```
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL
 } from '../constants/productConstants'

export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, products: [] }
        
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading:false, error: action.payload }
            
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
            
        default:
            return state    
     }
 }
```

Comment: For product_list_success action your payload is updating the "error" property in state. Is that intended or a typo?

Comment: Also, could you console.log your "products" in the HomeScreen component and share what the data looks like?

Comment: Greetings, sir. You have really helped me, because I have realized thanks to You, that there was a typo in the product_list_success action. The right code looks like this -
case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading:false, products: action.payload }


Thank You very much for Your kind effort.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure, how I could console.log the products. The products are being added through a Django model (which makes it easier to add the products in the Django admin panel). I am not really sure how it all works, because I am just a beginner and I am following a tutorial. At first we were loading products from products.js file. Things have changed since then, (at least I think so) but the problem mentioned in this SO post was solved, so it is excellent. :-)